# Flowtype. Create instance of class that implements interface with optional fields

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Here is an example

```
interface A {
  var1: string;
  var2?: string;
}

class B implements A {
   var1: string
}

const bInstance = new B({ var1: "sss" }) // no such constructor
```

Flow make me declare `var1` as class property. So what if i have `n` fields? Should i rewrite all of them or there is another way to solve it?

Flow doesn't make me declare `var2` as class property due to it's optional. Should i create `B` constructor manually as

```
constructor (a: any) {
  this.var1 = a.var1
  if (a.var2) {
    this.var2 = a.var2
  }
}
```

It look ugly. Does flow can't resolve such things automatically?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a known `n` number of fields, yes, you need to list all of them with their types. Otherwise—how would Flow understand the set of properties that are allowed?

If `n` is unknown, and you instead want to specify that the class can have any number of fields that are strings, you can instead consider a map:

```
interface A {
  someName: { [key: string]: string };
}
```

Keep in mind that with this format, the interface can't dictate what the exact names of those keys are.

As for your second question, your implementation of Class B…

```
class B implements A {
   var1: string
}
```

…will cause an error if you try to use the constructor in your question. When you defined `var2?: string;` on the interface, you told flow that "An implementing class *may* have `var2`, and if it does, it must be a string." But when you defined Class B, by not listing `var2`, Flow assumes B can never have `var2`. The interface type really doesn't help you shorten code, it only helps you ensure that your classes conform to a certain ruleset.

In the constructor, if you want to shorten your example, you can do something such as:

```
constructor (a: any) {
  Object.assign(this, a); // copy all properties of `a` to `this`
}
```

Regardless, I would highly recommend changing the type of `a` in your constructor to something more specific (or even just remove "`: any`"), else Flow will not be able to properly ensure you are passing in something appropriate.